# Where "bpm:activitiStartTask" is used in alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

[bpmModel.xml](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/bpmModel.xml) defines a `bpm:activitiStartTask` with comment:

> Ends automatically when workflow starts

But I have not found any examples where and how it can be used. Can somebody explain what it is and where can be used? As I see when workflow starts there is no any visible tasks are created, just one initial form form. No?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--                                                                                                                                                                           -->
    <!--  Amy start task implementing this marker aspect is automatically ended as soon as the workflow starts         -->
    <!-- Note this only applies to the Activiti Workflow Engine                                                                                      --> 
    <!--                                                                                                                                                                          -->

    <aspect name="bpm:endAutomatically" />
```

It will start the workflow automatically and pass it to the next task. It's useful when starting a workflow in Java and you don't want to pass a list of variables to it.